# Two linear functionals having the same Kernel are proportional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space, of finite dimension. Let $F,G:V\longrightarrow K$ be two non-zero $k$-linear applications. Suppose that $F$ and $G$ have the same kernel. Then $F$ and $G$ are proportional, i.e. there exists a non-zero scalar $\lambda$ such that $G=\lambda F$. Why?

I have a proof if I can assume there exists $v_0\in V$ such that $F(v_0)=1$. Can I always assume this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always assume this because $F$ is nonzero, so $F(x) = r \neq 0$ say for some $x \in V$. Then $F(x/r) = 1$.